# Chamar uma função Python pelo texto presente em uma variável

Tags: python

sou novo em Python e eu gostaria de saber se é possível eu chamar uma função pelo texto presente em uma variável, exemplo:

Peço ao usuário que digite o nome de uma função, e guardo oque foi digitado em **'func'** , após isso como chamar a função pelo que foi digitado pelo usuário ?

```
func = input('Diga o nome da função a ser executada!')
func()
```

ou - (Tendo em mente que as funções somar e mult já estão feitas)

```
func = 'somar'
result1 = func(3, 2)
func = 'mult'
result2 = func(3, 2)
print('O resultado é', result1, result2)
#---gostaria que resultasse
O resultado é 5 6
```

Sei q isto não dá certo, mais existe algo parecido com isto ?

Answer (score 1):

Bem parece estranho mas acabei conseguindo resolver o problema, pra quem tiver o mesmo problema é bem simples :

```
executar = locals()
func = 'somar'
result1 = executar[func](3, 2)
func = 'mult'
result2 = executar[func](3, 2)
print('O resultado é', result1, result2)
```

Isso é tudo :D ! Até mais...

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
def somar(x, y):
    soma = x + y
    print(soma)

func = input('Digite a função: ')
if func == 'somar':
    x = input('Insira o primeiro número: ')
    y = input('Insira o segundo número: ')
    somar(x, y)
```